# Printing Number Pattern in C

Tags: c, numbers, printf, logic

**input:** 'n' which will always be an odd number

**output for n=3**

```
 1
2 4
 3
```

**output for n=5**

```
  1
 2 4
3 5 7
 6 8
  9
```

Help me in understanding the logic.
What I could understood was that in each line the numbers are having a difference of 2.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you worked out what you should be seeing for n = 7?  When you have got that, then n = 9 and above should fall into place fairly readily.  You can then start working out how to encode the patterns.  AFAICS, you'll need one counter for the current number on odd-numbered lines (that prints odd numbers), and a second counter for the current number on even-numbered lines (that prints even numbers). You'll need to know how long the leading indentation on a line is, too, so as to get the alignment correct. You'll probably to use a format `%2d` (or perhaps `%-2d`, or `%.2d`) to print the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If your task is to write a program to print those patterns, I suggest you start smaller.  First write a program to print this pattern:

```
0 1 2
```

The outline of your program will look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       // you fill in something here
    }
}
```

That should be easy.  Once you get that to work, make a simple modification so it prints this:

```
1 2 3
```

That should be easy.  Once you get that to work, try writing a program to generate this pattern:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

That should be pretty easy.  Once you get that to work, try modifying it so it generates this pattern:

```
  1
 1 2
1 2 3
```

And once you get *that* to work, you can try printing the diamond patterns in your assignment.

Comment: I'm avg in printing patterns. This particular pattern is troubling me.